# simple html dom - Hung up on download urls

Tags: simple-html-dom

I'm running simple_html_dom to index links from a few websites. Sometimes I will come across a link that is actually a download file. For example, this link: "example.com/survey.html" - is actually a 500MB zip file download. It causes simple_html_dom to get stuck on the URL for minutes at a time and maxes out the memory. I tried setting the MAX_FILE_SIZE limit by using:

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 2000000);
```

This doesn't work... How can I get around these download files?

Thanks

Comment: Have you increased your PHP memory limit? You can add this at the top of your file (in simple_html_dom.php)
`ini_set('memory_limit','128M');`

Comment: I could increase the memory, but I was hoping there was a way to tell simple_html_dom to exclude checking downloadable files, and just check normal html website pages only.

Comment: How are you getting the pages? Are you using `curl`? `file_get_contents`?